# Permission denied while executing a command on a remote machine using pdsh

Tags: permissions

I am able to connect to a remote machine using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/adm/pdsh -l root -w "loop"
pdsh>
```

but when I try to execute any command it gives following error:

```
pdsh> cd /var
loop: Permission denied, please try again.
loop: Permission denied, please try again.
loop: Permission denied (publickey,password).
pdsh@rushi: loop: ssh exited with exit code 255
```

Please, can anyone provide any solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't have permission to log on the remote machine. When you type the first command `pdsh ...`, it really doesn't connect to the server. It does when you try to execute any command, like `cd /var`.
As `pdsh` is intended to execute commands in parallel, I suggest you to configure public key authentication:

1. Do `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on your server. You will be prompted to select the name and location of the key and the key.pub files.
2. Open the `.pub` file you generated on the previous step and copy the full text.
3. Paste that text on the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote server (loop). If the file does not exist you can create it safely. (Remember to set appropriate perms, like 600 ).
4. Profit!

Comment: If you have configured keys, it might also be you configured you key with a password. My version of pdsh will balk at that under normal run conditions. If so, generate a new key, leave it passwordless, copy it to the remote servers and try again.

Comment: @j03m You might want to post this as an answer as this has just hit me as well.